# Getting an error with sign up [Grails]

Tags: grails

i'm with an error that i can't find out how to solve it, i keep getting it when i try do register something

here's the form

```
<div id="divCadastro"></div> 
<g:form controller="aluno" action="save">          
    <label>Nome:</label>
    <g:textField name="nome"/><br>
    <label> RG:</label>
    <g:textField  name="rg"/><br>
    <label>CPF:</label>
    <g:textField  name="cpf"/><br>
    <label>RA:</label>
    <g:textField  name="ra"/><br>
    <label>Turma:</label>
    <g:textField name="turma"/><br>
    <label>Genero: </label>
    <select name="genero">
        <option value="m">Masculino</option>
        <option value="f">Feminino</option>            
    </select><br>
    <label>Código de Barras:</label>
    <g:textField name="cod_barras"/><br>    
    <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>
    <g:datePicker name="date" value="${new Date()}"  precision="day" noSelection="['':'-Escolha-']"/><br>    
    <label>Curso:</label>
    <g:select name="curso" from="${listaCurso}" optionValue="nome" optionKey="id"/>         
    <label>Endereço:</label>
    <g:textField  name="endereco"/><br>    
    <label>Número:</label>
    <g:textField name="nroendereco"/><br>
    <label>Telefone:</label>
    <g:textField name="telefone"/><br>
    <label>Bairro:</label>
    <g:textField  name="bairro"/><br>
    <label>Complemento:</label>
    <g:textField name="complemento"/><br>        
    <label>Cidade:</label>
    <g:select name="cidade" from="${listaCidade}" optionValue="nome" optionKey="id"/><br>         
    <label>Profissão:</label>
    <g:select name="profissao" from="${listaProfissao}" optionValue="nome" optionKey="id"/><br>     
    <label for="escolaridade">Escolaridade:</label>
    <g:select name="escolaridade" from="${listaEscolaridade}" optionValue="nome" optionKey="id"/><br>         
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <g:actionSubmit value="Salvar"/>
    <input type="button" name="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar"/> 
</g:form>
```

and here's the controller:

```
class AlunoController {
    def index() { 
        def listaAluno = Aluno.list()
        def listaCidade = Cidade.list()
        def listaProfissao = Profissao.list()
        def listaEscolaridade = Escolaridade.list()
        def listaCurso = Curso.list()
        render(view:"/aluno/index", model:[listaAluno:listaAluno, listaCidade:listaCidade,
                listaProfissao:listaProfissao, listaEscolaridade:listaEscolaridade, listaCurso:listaCurso])


    }
    def save(){
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno()
        aluno.nome = params.nome
        aluno.rg = params.rg
        aluno.cpf = params.cpf
        aluno.ra = params.ra
        aluno.turma = params.turma.toInteger()
        aluno.genero = params.genero
        aluno.nascimento = params.nascimento
        aluno.endereco = params.endereco
        aluno.nroendereco = params.nroendereco.toInteger()
        aluno.telefone = params.telefone            
        aluno.bairro = params.bairro
        aluno.complemento = params.complemento          
        aluno.cidade = Cidade.get(params.cidade)    
        aluno.profissao = Profissao.get(params.profissao)
        aluno.escolaridade = Escolaridade.get(params.escolaridade)
        aluno.curso = Curso.get(params.curso)

        aluno.save(flush:true)
        render "Sucesso"
    }
   }
```

when i fill up the fields end click on 'Salvar', i get the error:

• Error: Page Not Found (404)

• Path: /aluno/save

what am i missing?

Thanks!

@Edit
i'm using grails 3.1.6 and where's my url mapping:

```
package eventosunipar
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Grails version? Could you paste conf/UrlMappings.groovy?

Comment: there, i added the infos

Comment: do a println "test" at the top and after save see if it hits them in save action change render "successo" to render text: "successo" see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

`<g:actionSubmit value="Salvar"/>` - actionSubmit is a button to submit to different actions from single form as stated in documentation: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html If `action` parameter is not set in this button, it defaults to value, in your case `Salvar`. Add `action="save"` to your button definition or use standard `<input type="submit" ... />` tag (I would suggest this option).

If this doesn't work, show generated HTML of the page with form from your browser